# Is the Angular Material CSS (Layout) tightly couple now, to the Angular Material JS (Framework)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

previously (about 6 month ago) I was able to fork and used only the angular material css layout in my application.
I am not using the angular material js part of the framework. I tried to update my the css layout with the latest and greatest of angular material but its not working any-more... 
Is there now a tightly couple dependence of one on the other now ?
How can I use this layout outside Angular Material ?

Comment: I don't think so. It's mostly just CSS. https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.0.5/src/core/services/layout/layout.scss

Comment: "Knowing" is what I am after... From my test you can't any-more.

Comment: If you had taken the time to look at the link and the folder the file is in, you would "know". There is 2 SCSS files and one Javascript file. All the javascript does, is validate the usage of the attributes. Like I said, it's just CSS in the end, it has nothing to to with any framework. The browser understands it. If your use-case is not working, maybe the API has changed. Nobody can tell, since you didn't add an example.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong, ( I would like you to be right,  and thank you for your feedback ) have a look at this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ngmaterial/pzbpefrxpqg But If you make it work please share a live example ;)

Comment: Here are some basic examples: http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/LGoQNv. If you have a specific requirement please update your question.

Comment: I see, but the recommended use of the layout doesn't work anymore unfortunately http://codepen.io/Bretto/pen/LGKpWN

Comment: The CSS is not targeting the attributes anymore, but you can translate any attribute to a CSS class and use all of the angular material layout. Write a couple regexp rules and replace it in all of your files.